# Unable to read IPC::Open3 child's output

Tags: perl, pipe

This code is used to read and write through the pipe, but it seems it is not working well.

```
use strict;
use IPC::Open2;


my $st1="String1\n";
my $st2="String2\n";
my $st3="String3\n";
my $st4="String4\n";
my $st5="String5\n";

my $joint=$st1.$st2.$st3.$st4.$st5;
my $r;
my $pid = open2(\*CHILD_IN, \*CHILD_OUT, 'java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -cp abc.jar:xxx.jar TestCode')
or die "open2() failed $!";
print CHILD_IN $joint;
$r=<CHILD_OUT>;
print "Got $r from child\n";
print "[OUTPUT]: $_" while (<CHILD_OUT>);
```

This code is only reading first line of the output that too which is stored in $r. Not going inside while loop. Although there is a lot of output by executing the command.

Comment: `die "open2() failed $!"` will never execute beacuse `open3` throws an exception on error.

Comment: More importantly, your code suffers from a race condition. If the child writes a large amount to STDERR, it will block since the parent is blocked reading from the child's STDOUT. `open3` is a really low level module. You should be using IPC::Run3 or IPC::Run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
$r=<CHLD_OUT>;
```

and

```
print "[OUTPUT]: $_" while (<CHILD_OUT>);
```

It's *CHLD_OUT* versus *CHILD_OUT*.

It's probably better to always use

```
use warnings
```

It'd save you from the trouble, by showing a warning message:

```
readline() on unopened filehandle CHILD_OUT at x.pl line 19.
```